# no aparece grafica con dos consultas php a mi base de datos

Tags: php, highcharts

Estoy realizando un proyecto de un medidor de temperatura analógico que vuelca la fecha y la medida a una base de datos y quería hacer en php una gráfica con highcharts consultando la fecha y la medida para representarlo en un gráfico de lineas.
La consulta funciona (la probé por separado, apunta a una columna de la db llamada fecha y otra llamada temperatura) pero me ocurre una cosa curiosa: tengo dos consultas distintas, una para el eje x (categories) y otra para el y (data). Si pongo solo una de los dos consultas, ya sea data o categories, la gráfica aparece (las adjunto abajo), pero si pongo las dos juntas, no muestra ninguna gráfica.
No soy mas que un novato en programación y no encuentro donde esta el fallo. ¿Podríais ayudarme? Mil gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="code/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="code/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"> 
</div>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "estacion_meteo";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$result = mysqli_query ($conn,"SELECT * FROM datos");

?>



        <script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
    type: 'line'
},
title: {
    text: 'Medición de Temperatura'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Estación Metereológica'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: [<?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo "['".$row["fecha"]."'],";
    }
?>]
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        },
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Temperatura',
    data: [

            <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo "[".$row["temperatura"]."],";
    }
?>



    ]

}]
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Esta es la imagen si pongo valores de temperatura manuales (3,4,5)]

[image: Imagen con valores de categorías manuales]

[image: Imagen con las dos consultas juntas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error es que abres dos bucles sin necesidad. Me refiero a esto: `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)`. Es preciso entender que cuando obtienes los datos, los cuales en este caso se encuentran en `$result`, lo que tienes ahí es un puntero  hacia los datos, y cada vez que aplicas un  `fetch` mueves el puntero. Si tú aplicas el `while` dos veces significa que la segunda vez el puntero estará ya vacío, puesto que en el primer `while` ya lo recorriste completo. En consecuencia, tienes que obtener todos los datos dentro del primer `while`.

Prueba del siguiente modo. La idea aquí es obtener los datos de la fila `temperatura` dentro del único `while`, guardarlos en la variable `$temperaturas` y luego colocarlos dentro del elemento `data` correspondiente.

Dado que el código es algo confuso puede que no sea exactamente así y haya que adaptarlo. Al menos lo que se ve es que dentro de `data` iría un array se temperaturas. Si no funciona agradezco que muestres en la pregunta un ejemplo del objeto final que debe construirse para poder ayudarte mejor. La clave es usar el  `while`  una sola vez, para sacar de él los datos que necesites. El error es, como necesitas los datos en dos partes distintas, haber usado el `while` dos veces.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="code/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="code/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"> 
</div>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "estacion_meteo";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$result = mysqli_query ($conn,"SELECT * FROM datos");
$temperaturas=array();
?>



        <script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
    type: 'line'
},
title: {
    text: 'Medición de Temperatura'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Estación Metereológica'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: [<?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            echo "['".$row["fecha"]."'],";
            #Aunque estos datos son de yAxis los guardamos desde ahora
            #porque estamos recorriendo en este bloque el puntero de los datos
            $temperaturas[]=$row["temperatura"];
    }
?>]
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        },
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Temperatura',
    data: [ 
            <?php $temperaturas; #Asignamos los datos guardados en el while
?>
           ]

}]
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

> ## EDIT
>
> ### Propuesta basada en tu respuesta
>
> Aunque funcione, el código no está optimizado haciendo dos veces la
>   misma consulta. Puedes probar algo así:
>
> ```
> #Creamos dos variables para concatenar los valores de cada dato diferenciado
> $categories="categories: [";
> $data="data: [";
>
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos";
> $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
> while ($registros=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
> {
>   #Se concatena el dato de cada columna a la variable que corresponde
>   $categories.= "$registros[fecha] ,";
>   $data.= "$registros[temperatura] ,";
> }
> #Se cierra cada variable
> $categories.="]";
> $data.="]";
>
> #Se imprimen las variables
> echo $categories;
> echo $data;
> ```

Comment: Hola! Lo primero muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Probé tu solución pero me sigue pasando lo mismo, no aparece la grafica por ninguna parte. Trasteando con tu idea he encontrado la solución que, básicamente era lo que tu indicabas pero haciendo un cambio. La pego debajo y te pongo como acertada tu respuesta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente conseguí solucionarlo haciendo las consultas por separado:

```
categories: [

                    <?php 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos";
                    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    while ($registros=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                    {
                    ?>       
                        '<?php echo $registros["fecha"] ?>',
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
        ]
```

Y en la otra serie de datos:

```
data: [
             <?php 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos";
                    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    while ($registros=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                    {
                    ?>       
                        <?php echo $registros["temperatura"] ?>,
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>               

    ]
```

Comment: Aunque funcione el código no está optimizado, porque consultas dos veces a la base de datos sin necesidad. Hay que buscar la forma de concatenar cada dato, dentro en un solo `while`. Revisa mi respuesta al final, en la parte del **EDIT**, donde he intentando emular lo mismo que haces en tu doble lectura, pero mediante un solo `while`. Allí he usado dos variables distintas para concatenar cada dato y al final imprimo las variables. Así debería funcionar.